# Play windows media services streaming on Android

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, wms, asx

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running Windows Media Services to stream content online by http, I need to develop an application on Android to play transmissions through its url, eg `http://server/stream.asx`
I try using Vitamio, but it did not work, someone who knows that i can do, Thanks